# fscanf returns (null)

Tags: c, scanf

When running the following code:

```
FILE *input;
char *name=NULL,*stat=NULL;
int i=0,j=0;
input=fopen("/proc/1/stat","r");
fscanf(input,"%d",&i);
fscanf(input,"%s",name);
fscanf(input,"%s",stat);
fscanf(input,"%d",&j);
printf("pid : %d name: %s status: %s ppid: %d",i,name,stat,j);
```

I get the output:

> ```
> pid : 1 name: (null) status: (null) ppid: 0
> ```

The content of /proc/1/stat is

> 1 (init) S 0

Can you please tell me what i did wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us the type of these variables ?

Comment: Did you initialize name and stat before read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` and `stat` must NOT be NULL... you must initialize them - by defining them directly as an array like `char name [LENGTH]`...

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize both name and stat either with a malloc or

```
char name[LENGTH];
```

if you just write

```
char *name;
```

It wouldn't work

Answer (score -1):

I run your code and it works.

```
FILE *input;
input = fopen("stat","r");

int i, j;
char name[100], stat[100];

fscanf(input,"%d", &i);
fscanf(input," %s", name);
fscanf(input," %s", stat);
fscanf(input," %d", &j);
printf("pid : %d name: %s status: %s ppid: %d", i, name, stat, j);
```

If you are facing some kinds of buffer problem you can try following code...

```
int i, j;
char name[100], stat[100], temp[200];

fscanf(input, " %[^\n]s", temp);
sscanf(temp, "%d %s %s %d", &i, name, stat, &j);
printf("pid : %d name: %s status: %s ppid: %d\n", i, name, stat, j);
```

Comment: `" %[^\n]s"`is bad, it must be `"%199[^\n]"` and so on

Comment: @user411313, can I ask why "%[^\n]s" is bad?

Comment: Buffer overflow...unless you tell the `scanf()` family of routines how big the maximum string sizes are, they are vulnerable to buffer overflow.